# *ngFor fails in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngfor

I am trying use *ngFor to access array of objects. But it is throwing console errors.I have defined the array like this.

```
     employees=[ 
        {name:'a',age:'25'},
        {name:'b',age:'35'}
        ];
```

In the html template file i am using *ngFor statements like this

```
        <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let employee of employees ; let i = index;">
           {{name}}
        </li>
       </ul>
```

The browser throws console error like the below( the plukr is @ http://plnkr.co/edit/0cBHaDM1mHvMf38NtQ7X?p=preview)

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Array[2] is not a constructor
TypeError: Array[2] is not a constructor
    at new AppComponent (http://run.plnkr.co/0tyHWvPl7PnWfPkm/app/app.component.ts!transpiled:15:26)
    at new Wrapper_AppComponent

I am a bit new to Angular 2 and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistakes

1. You used the markup in index.html.
2. `employees= new Array[2];` is not the way to instanciate an Array.
3. `names = new Array('qw','er');` invalid.
4. Did not use a constructor to assign values.(Bad practice)

Your code should be as

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hellotest {{name}}</h1>
  <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let name of names ; let j = index;">
           {{name}}
           </li>
       </ul>
        <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let employee of employees ; let i = index;">
           {{employee.name}}
        </li>
       </ul>
       `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';
  employees= new Array();
  names = new Array();
  constructor(){
  this.employees=[ 
    {name:'a',age:'25'},
    {name:'b',age:'35'}
    ];

  this.names=['qw','er'];
  console.log(this.employees);
  console.log(this.names);
  }
}
```

**[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7CB8lbYu3WgmWteo2Kbp?p=preview)**

If you don't want to use a constructor then you should be using the variable declarations as below

```
  name = 'Angular';
  employees:any[]= [ 
    {name:'a',age:'25'},
    {name:'b',age:'35'}
    ];
  names:Array<string> = ['qw','er'];
```

**[No Constructor plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIA6B6PtegxOiicGDraP?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks..that helps

Answer (score 3):

Please change your layout to this:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let employee of employees ; let i = index;">
      {{employee.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

The employee variable will be each element of your array, then you need to access the name property of this obeject